# Hadoop Single Node Cluster setup error during namenode format

Tags: hadoop, namenode

I have installed Apache Hadoop 2.6.0 in Windows 10. I have been trying to fix this issue but failed to understand the error or any mistake from my end.

I have set up all the paths correctly, Hadoop version is showing the version in command prompt properly.

I have already created `temp` directory inside hadoop directory like `c:\hadoop\temp`.

When I am trying to format the Namenode, I am getting this error:

```
C:\hadoop\bin>hdfs namenode -format
18/07/18 20:44:55 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = TheBhaskarDas/192.168.44.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.5
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = C:\hadoop\etc\hadoop;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\activation-1.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\asm-3.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\avro-1.7.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-codec-1.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-configuration-1.6.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-el-1.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-math3-3.1.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-net-3.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\curator-client-2.6.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\curator-framework-2.6.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\guava-11.0.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\hadoop-annotations-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\hadoop-auth-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\htrace-core-3.0.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\httpclient-4.2.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\httpcore-4.2.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jersey-core-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jersey-json-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jersey-server-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jets3t-0.9.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jettison-1.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jetty-6.1.26.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jsch-0.1.42.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jsp-api-2.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\junit-4.11.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\mockito-all-1.8.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\netty-3.6.2.Final.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\paranamer-2.3.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\stax-api-1.0-2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\xmlenc-0.52.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\xz-1.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\zookeeper-3.4.6.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\hadoop-common-2.6.5-tests.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\hadoop-nfs-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\asm-3.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-codec-1.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-el-1.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\guava-11.0.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\htrace-core-3.0.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jersey-core-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jersey-server-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jetty-6.1.26.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jsp-api-2.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\netty-3.6.2.Final.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\xmlenc-0.52.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-2.6.5-tests.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\activation-1.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\asm-3.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-codec-1.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\guava-11.0.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\guice-3.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\guice-servlet-3.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jersey-client-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jersey-core-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jersey-guice-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jersey-json-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jersey-server-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jettison-1.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jetty-6.1.26.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jline-0.9.94.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\netty-3.6.2.Final.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\stax-api-1.0-2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\xz-1.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\zookeeper-3.4.6.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\asm-3.2.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\avro-1.7.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\guice-3.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\guice-servlet-3.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\hadoop-annotations-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\jersey-core-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\jersey-guice-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\jersey-server-1.9.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\junit-4.11.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\netty-3.6.2.Final.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\paranamer-2.3.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\xz-1.0.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.5-tests.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.5.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.5.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git -r e8c9fe0b4c252caf2ebf1464220599650f119997; compiled by 'sjlee' on 2016-10-02T23:43Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_181
************************************************************/
18/07/18 20:44:55 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
[Fatal Error] core-site.xml:19:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
18/07/18 20:44:55 FATAL conf.Configuration: error parsing conf core-site.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1071)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setBoolean(Configuration.java:1409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:319)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:485)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1512)
18/07/18 20:44:55 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1071)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setBoolean(Configuration.java:1409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:319)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:485)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1512)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2491)
        ... 11 more
18/07/18 20:44:55 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
18/07/18 20:44:55 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at TheBhaskarDas/192.168.44.1
************************************************************/

C:\hadoop\bin>
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>C:\hadoop\temp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:50071</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed it.

I have removed all the characters/anything before `<?xml` and validated the XML files in https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

new **core-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->


<!--
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>\hadoop\temp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:50071</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```